# bootstrap select dropdown loading issue

Tags: c#, jquery, css

I am using bootstrap select drop down plugins. https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/. in the select drop down I have more than 50,000 options. so when click on drop down it is take minimum 1 to 2 min to open and when page is loading that time browser is hang. so someone have idea to resolve this issue???

Comment: You might consider using AJAX to load and paginate data instead of loading everything.

Comment: you can use auto complete instead of dropdown

Comment: This is a known issue in the bootstrap library. If you use ajax it will stuck your screen for a few seconds. The only solution here is to not have too many options or use select2 maybe

Answer (score 0):

See [this **Ajax-Bootstrap-Select** on github](https://github.com/truckingsim/Ajax-Bootstrap-Select)

It is extends existing Bootstrap Select implementations by adding the ability to search via AJAX requests as you type.

Answer (score 0):

Show 50,000 option on drop down is bad idea. It will definitely take time to open.
1:You need Use auto complete text box when user type record will search from database and show in auto complete list.
2:Second option is load these record and assign to auto compete data source so it will avoiding so many connection to database.

Follow these link 
[Auto Complete Drop Down](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)